# Can you add [formControl] dynamically to slotted input?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am trying to make a wrapper that manages input styling, positioning and error validation styles while not wrapping native input types in long custom components that don't have self closing tags.

It operates similarly to the concept of element context.

I have named this wrapper component `<form-entry>` and it's used like this:

```html
<form-entry [formControlRef]="this.form.controls['bookingTitle']">
  <h1>Booking Title</h1>
  <h2>Summary text to be displayed when searching up this booking</h2>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Booking Title" />
</form-entry>

<form-entry [formControlRef]="this.form.controls['bookingNotes']">
  <h1>Booking Notes</h1>
  <h2>Additional Booking Details</h2>
  <textarea auto-resizable placeholder="Extra Notes"></textarea>
</form-entry>
```

Applying styles and formatting to the nested elements

[image]

This is pretty ergonomic because I have access to the field errors from within the `<form-entry>` component, allowing me to display validation errors.

However I would love to be able to forward the `FormControl` reference to the slotted `<input>`, `<textarea>`, etc elements from within the `<form-entry>` component.

I can get around this by adding a `[formControl]` directive to the input directly but it adds a point of failure having to maintain synchronization between the wrapper and the input.

```html
<form-entry [errorMessages]="getFirstError(this.form.controls['title'])">
  <h1>Booking Title</h1>
  <h2>Summary text to be displayed when searching up this booking</h2>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="Booking Title" 
    [formControl]="asFormControl(this.form.controls['title'])" />
</form-entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use your approach that pass the formControl

   ```
   <form-entry>
     <h1>Booking Title</h1>
     <h2>Summary text to be displayed when searching up this booking</h2>
     <input 
       type="text" 
       placeholder="Booking Title" 
       [formControl]="asFormControl(this.form.controls['title'])" />
   </form-entry>
   ```

   You can get the FormControl from your component as

   ```
   @ContentChild(NgControl) control:NgControl

   //And you has in this.control.control the formControl, so

   {{control.control.errors}} //are the errors
   ```
2. If you pass the formControl as input in the form-entry, you need
   relationate the input and text area with the control. Before I want to say that I like use the input to get a FormControl in the way)

   ```
   formControlRef:FormControl
   @Input('formControlRef') set _(value){
        this.formControlRef=value as FormControl
   }
   ```

   To relationate the "input" and the "text" and "textarea" you can use a directive

   ```
   @Directive({
     selector: 'form-entry input,form-entry textArea',
   })
   export class FormEntryDirective implements OnInit,AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
     subscription: any;
     formControl: FormControl;
     constructor(
       private elementRef: ElementRef,
       @Optional() @Host() private parent: FormEntryComponent
     ) {}
     ngOnInit() {
       this.subscription = fromEvent(
         this.elementRef.nativeElement,
         'input'
       ).subscribe((res: any) => {
         const control = this.parent ? this.parent.formControlRef : null;
         if (control) control.setValue(res.target.value);
       });
     }
     ngAfterViewInit()
     {
        const control = this.parent ? this.parent.formControlRef : null;
        if (control && control.value)
           this.elementRef.nativeElement.value=control.value
     }

     ngOnDestroy() {
       this.subscription.unsubscribe();
     }
   }
   ```

See the selector is in the way `form-entry input, form-entry textarea`. That's is applied to all the inputs and textarea that are inside a "tag" form-entr (the selector of your component)

See [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ust3mo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-entry.component.ts) with the two approach